# Microsoft Dynamics 2013 and Microsoft Dynamics 365 works with same Rest API?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

I am working on an **extension** for dynamics.

Here i want to use dynamics api.

One client uses **Microsoft Dynamics 365 (Rest API)** and

another client uses **Microsoft Dynamics 2013**.

Can i use **same api to serve both** the clients ?

Currently i am using api's from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/web-api-functions-actions-sample-csharp

Will it work for **Microsoft Dynamics 2013**?

Answer (score 1):

The Dynamics 365 Web API did not exist in CRM 2013, so you cannot use that for both purposes.

Instead you can use the [Organization Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/use-microsoft-dynamics-365-organization-service) (also called the CRM 2011 endpoint). The behavior of this endpoint has been relatively consistent (with some minor changes to how e.g. updates should be made) from CRM 2013 to D365.

Be aware that the Organization Service [will be removed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn281891.aspx#Anchor_2) at some point in the future, but currently works just fine:

> The Web API is intended to replace the CRM 2011 endpoint, also known
>   as the SOAP endpoint, for accessing the Dynamics 365 organization web
>   service and other provided web services.
>
> As of the release of Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online 2016 Update 1 and
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 Service Pack 1 (8.1.0), the CRM 2011
>   endpoint has been deprecated. The 2011 endpoint will be removed some
>   time after the release of Dynamics 365 version 9.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot use D365 Web API for both.
I found this is useful for CRM 2013.
http://xrmenterprise.com/2013/09/microsoft-dynamics-crm-2013-client-api-cheat-sheet/